# Why do we say "misogyny" and not "gynemisia"?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek

The Greek prefixes *phobia* and *philia* are commonly used in many words, such as 'gynephilia' and 'androphilia'. Why is 'miso' (from the Greek μῖσος) primarily used as a prefix in words such as 'misogyny' and 'misogamy'? From an etymological standpoint, would it make sense to use 'gynemisia' instead of 'misogyny'?

Comment: You might find these other question relevant: [one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/why-hippopotamus-instead-of-potamohippus) & [two](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/rules-to-constructing-a-proper-compound-noun-in-ancient-greek).

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, but it's worth noting that this formation is also common in Greek. See, for instance (with a bunch of false positives), [this list of Greek verbs beginning with *miso-*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=miso&lang=greek). (You can find a similar list for *philo-*.) It's still an interesting question, but I don't think the problem has to do with etymology from Greek.

Comment: Note also philosophy (and philology etc) rather than \*\*sophophilia.

Comment: If you imagined the verb formed before the noun, however, as in φιλοσοφεῖν > φιλοσοφία, φιλαδελφεῖν > φιλαδελφία, φιλομανθάνειν > φιλομάθεια...? Just a thought, perhaps to tack onto the question...

Comment: In Greek, a compound noun/adjective formed by a verb and its object sometimes has the verb part in the front. (Almost) all nouns with *-phobia* and *-philia* are post-Greek, and therefore do not follow the pattern.

Comment: Why do we call him Phillip, and not Hippophile?